# Разработка клиентского приложения для ruSO

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, stackoverflow

Всем привет!

Возникла идея о создании приложения для *Stack Overflow на русском*, но у сайта нет *API*. Почему? Мне кажется, что мобильное приложение было бы хорошим дополнением, ведь ресурс бьет рекорды посещаемости.

Дело в том, что не всегда компьютер под рукой, а вопрос задать хочется. Приложение, конечно же, есть, но я не вижу ничего интересного в нем, т.к. оно просто грузит мобильную версию сообщества. А ведь хочется большего: список вопросов, комментарии, голоса, всякого рода уведомления. Было бы прекрасно.

Comment: эээ.... 1. API есть. 2. Полноценный клиент под андроид по крайней мере есть, с уведомлениями, да. Причем для всех сообществ разом.

Comment: API [есть](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Делайте)

Comment: Читаю вопрос с мобильного приложения. )

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-завершено]? :D

Comment: @D-side [tag:статус-давным-давно-завершено]

Comment: @Flippy, можете написать приложение для работы с чатами SO. [Штатное приложение не поддерживает их](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35391171#35391171). Учитывая, что инфраструктура чатов общая для всех сайтов системы StackExchange, оно много кому может быть нужным.

Comment: @Arhad кстати, я уже где-то видел такое приложение, но оно давно не обновлялось.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315791/260198 может когда-нибудь в опенсорс выложат текущие приложения

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Читаем вполне достойное [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Любуемся на приложения для [андроида](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) (довольно удобное) и [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) (не пользовался, но должно быть похоже).

Comment: Вот это я безглазый ) Искал ruSO клиент, забыл что это часть Stack Excange

Comment: @СергейГрушин это бонус слияния Хэшкода с SE – приложение в подарок.